Two stacked 100 percent bar charts
Hoping to get a pair of 100% stacked bar charts that looks like this:

What I have so far:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfInd = pd.DataFrame({
    'Winner': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Neither'],
    'percent_cum': [13, 48, 100],
    'y_value': ['1', '1', '1']
})

dfGen = pd.DataFrame({
    'Winner': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Neither'],
    'percent_cum': [20, 53, 100],
    'y_value': ['2', '2', '2']
})

dfInd_1 = dfInd.iloc[[0]]
dfInd_2 = dfInd.iloc[[1]]
dfInd_3 = dfInd.iloc[[2]]

dfGen_1 = dfGen.iloc[[0]]
dfGen_2 = dfGen.iloc[[1]]
dfGen_3 = dfGen.iloc[[2]]


sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

# Initialize the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))


sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_3,
            color='#efedf5',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_2,
            color='#bcbddc',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_1,
            color='#756bb1',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_3,
            color='#efedf5',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_2,
            color='#bcbddc',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_1,
            color='#756bb1',ax=None)

My problem: bar chart representing dfInd is overlaid on dfGen.
I've tried to solve by indicating the y_values for each dataframe (1 for dfInd, 2 for dfGen). My thinking was that this would shift dfInd up the y axis by one.  This didn't work: when I add  sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", y="y_value",data=dfInd_1, color='#756bb1',ax=None) I end up getting a big block.

Add y="y_value" to each of your barplot command
sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_3, y='y_value',
            color='#efedf5',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_2, y='y_value',
            color='#bcbddc',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_1, y='y_value',
            color='#756bb1',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_3, y='y_value',
            color='#efedf5',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_2, y='y_value',
            color='#bcbddc',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_1, y='y_value',
            color='#756bb1',ax=None)


Obviously, then, you may want to change that field name, and/or to change that field value. If you don't want  lines to appear as "1" and "2", change
    'y_value': ['1', '1', '1']

to
    'y_value': ['dfInd', 'dfInd', 'dfInd']

Or, without changing y_value, nor passing explicit strings (singleton array containing those strings) as y, you can also assign displayed labels to the y_value values by running at the end
plt.yticks(['1','2'], ['dfGen', 'dfInd'])

Likewise, you may change the axis displayed axe with some other name than y_value with
plt.ylabel("Dataframe")

Or, alternatively, if for some reason you can't use that y_value (because it has another role. But I feel that its only role was an attempt to use it exactly for what your question is about), you can also pass an array instead of a string for y, so that you can force y value directly in the barplot line
sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_3, y=['dfGen'],
            color='#efedf5',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_2, y=['dfGen'],
            color='#bcbddc',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_1, y=['dfGen'],
            color='#756bb1',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_3, y=['dfInd'],
            color='#efedf5',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_2, y=['dfInd'],
            color='#bcbddc',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_1, y=['dfInd'],
            color='#756bb1',ax=None)

(Note that 1 element is enough in the array since it is the same y for all data each time. We can't pass just the string, because it would be interpreted, with seaborn, as a field name. Hence the, otherwise useless, singleton array)

Complete code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfInd = pd.DataFrame({
    'Winner': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Neither'],
    'percent_cum': [13, 48, 100],
    'y_value': ['1', '1', '1']
})

dfGen = pd.DataFrame({
    'Winner': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Neither'],
    'percent_cum': [20, 53, 100],
    'y_value': ['2', '2', '2']
})

dfInd_1 = dfInd.iloc[[0]]
dfInd_2 = dfInd.iloc[[1]]
dfInd_3 = dfInd.iloc[[2]]

dfGen_1 = dfGen.iloc[[0]]
dfGen_2 = dfGen.iloc[[1]]
dfGen_3 = dfGen.iloc[[2]]


sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

# Initialize the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))


sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_3, y='y_value',
            color='#efedf5',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_2, y='y_value',
            color='#bcbddc',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfGen_1, y='y_value',
            color='#756bb1',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_3, y='y_value',
            color='#efedf5',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_2, y='y_value',
            color='#bcbddc',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="percent_cum", data=dfInd_1, y='y_value',
            color='#756bb1',ax=None)

plt.yticks(['1','2'], ['dfGen', 'dfInd'])
plt.ylabel("Dataframe")
plt.show()


Thank you for helping @chrslg.  Can you post your entire code?  I'm still getting the second bar chart overlaid on top of the first, and am wondering if you've added a code for axis that I don't have?  I tried running your code in both Spyder and VScode, in case it was an editor problem, but no dice in either.

@oymonk There are several versions in my message. But I posted the one that implies the least change from yours: No change on data. No change on barplot lines, but for the specification of y. And 2 lines to "translate" from '1'/'2' to 'dfGen'/'dfInd'

thank you for posting the entire code.  Still getting overlaid!  So bizarre because yours clearly works based on the screenshot you provided.

I still wasn't able to make it work.  I moved the data around in the dataset and got something working (alternative answer below).

The problem with the original is that it is asking the program to plot six bar charts, each with one y value. All these bar charts are laid on top of one another, making it impossible to see some of the charts.  In what follows, three bar charts are created, each with two y values. Doing so creates separation on the y axis.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dog': [13, 20],
    'Cat': [48, 53],
    'Neither': [100, 100],
    'Population': ['DfInd', 'DfGen']
})

print(df)


sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

# Initialize the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))

sns.barplot(x="Neither", data=df, y='Population',
            color='#efedf5',ax=None)

sns.barplot(x="Cat", data=df, y='Population',
            color='#bcbddc',ax=None)


sns.barplot(x="Dog", data=df, y='Population',
            color='#756bb1',ax=None)

